# Tissue based image segmentation

Tags: opencv, image-processing, cimg

I'm working on a project to do a segmentation of tissu. So far i so good for now. But her i want to segment the destructed from the good tissu. Her is an image example. So as you can see the good tissus are smooth and the destructed ones are not. I have the idea to detected the edges to do the segmentation but it give bad results.

I'm opening to any i'm open to any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: What's good tissue? Destructed tissue? What you mean for _smooth_? What are bad results? What's desidered result? What have you done so far? Etc...

Comment: Well as in the exampel, the good tissus are the tissu with homogenous green. The bad ones are with heterogeneous green. I said that i try to detect the edges with sobel filter because as you know with the edges we can detect the heterogeneity in the image, but this does not work, it give many false result (detect bad tissu as bad one).                                                                                                           http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/78703614010194A00101a090.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple approach which can be used as an intermediate test could be following:

1. Blur the image to reduce the noise. This is an important step. OpenCV provides an inbuilt method for it.
2. Find contours using the OpenCV method `findContour()`.
3. Then if the perimeter of contour is greater than a set threshold (you will have to set a value) then, you can consider it to be a smooth tissue else you can discard the tissue.

This is a really simple approach and a simple program can be written for it really fast.

Answer (score 2):

Use a convolutional neural network for example any prebuilt in the Caffe package.  Label the different kinds of areas in as many images as you have, then use many (1000s) small (32x32) patches from those to train the network. This will produce much better results than any kind of handcrafted algorithm.

Comment: you're absolutely correct, given that someone else is producing training patches :D